# How to solve Captcha problem in TOR?

Tags: captcha

I'm having problems with captcha in TOR. A website I am trying to register on has an 'I am not a robot button', which when I click it comes up with a message saying:

> Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4):

Many identified exit nodes have been blacklisted on some websites, and your current exit node is on that blacklist. You could try changing your exit node, but honestly in the end **you're just going to have to deal with the Captchas.**

Answer (score 3):

Well, a "captcha case" is quite common one using Tor. You need to change the exit node to try again - the problem is that there're not-so-much-as-needed exits and you can hit a hevily-used exit node, or an abused one. So - just change it and try again! it's a trial-and-error approach, nothing else. A control protocol command is "SIGNAL NEWNYM"

Answer (score 0):

To use captchas: Change your security level to `Safest`, then resolve them and gain access. After, change back your security level again to `Standard`.